# FB like page not working?

Tags: html, css, facebook

I'm try to add the Facebook Like Page feature to my website and it just isn't working. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong? I've paste the code into the html and then positioned it using CSS. Here it all is:

**.html**

```
<div id="fb-root">
<script>(function(d, s, id) {var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/all.js#xfbml=1";
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script></div>
```

**.css**

```
.fb-root{
 margin: -900px 500px;
 }
```

Thanks in advance for answering my question!

Comment: Why are you using -900px margins ?

Comment: @Nibbler its placing it where I want. Am I not suppose to use them?

Comment: it's possible to see your page ? Or can you create a fiddle ?

Comment: @Nibbler here http://i43.tinypic.com/hvv2h1.png

Comment: try to create a fiddle of your page to see your code.

http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: @Nibbler Sorry, is their something wrong with using -900px? I've set margin: 0; border: 0; padding:0; at the start

Comment: It's not good to use negative margins with so big values, negative margins can be good to have some minor changes, not to positioning elements like that. And i think that you can't see the element because of that.

Comment: @Nibbler How else shall I position it? Have you get any other methods?

Comment: That's why i was asking to see your code, to try to help you with positioning.

Comment: @Nibbler Okay dude, please bare with me

Comment: @Nibbler http://pastebin.com/w0BuGuCB There you go

Comment: @nibbler sorry I cannot supply the HTML at this moment in time as I'm not anywhere near my pc

Comment: Ok i will try to do something

Comment: @Nibbler Not a problem! Can you please explain what you are going to do? The -900 margins work perfectly on everything, but if you're recommending not to use them then I won't

Comment: I just recomend it because i think it's not the best pratice to positioning the elements. You can define them without using negative margins. But that's just my point of view mate.

Comment: Would you say that's your personal recommendation

Comment: @Nibbler like their isn't any specific way of doing it right? There's lots of different methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this is the code you put on your question

```
 <div id="fb-root"></div>
 <script>(function(d, s, id) {
   var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
   if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
   js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
   js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
   fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

Do you have this class on it too ?

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/" data-layout="standard" data-action="like" data-show-faces="true" data-share="false"></div>
```

Do you missed this one on your question ?

Another thing. If you don't have a server, try to run your page with wamp or something.

If you already have a server try to upload your page to the server and see if you can see the "button". Don't forget to include that code on your page.

About the css forget about .fb-root. You're are defining a class and at your html you have an id.

So now you have to define the positioning of the button, to match your code change your css to

```
 .fb-like{
  margin: -900px 500px;
 }
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Yeah thanks dude! Also I see you used -900px.. Was wondering did your method of positioning go to plan or?

Comment: Yes mate, i'm creating something based on your layout to give you some lights, will post it soon.

Comment: @AdzT1 This is just an example, hope it give you some lights

http://jsfiddle.net/4Av4p/

Comment: Thanks, I will inspect it now

Answer (score 0):

Facebook actually gives you a way to do this at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button/
You put in what you want then click 'Get Code' and it'll give you the code to embed it into your site.

Comment: I've done that. It's just not displaying on my webpage and I don't have a clue why.